# jQuery Mobile Multi-page structure with Panel navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, navigation

Right now I have multiple pages inside one document, and I want to control navigation between the pages using jQM 1.3's Panel widget. Problem lies with the fact that as of now, Panels have to be inside Pages.

Is there some way to do this without having to duplicate the same panel navigation over and over inside each page?

Answer (score 1):

I use [jQuery.View](http://javascriptmvc.com/docs.html#!jQuery.View) from the javascript mvc librairy for client side templating it works great. Take a look at "From File" section, it allows you write a template and bind data to it.  You could import the Panel widget in each page.